# How to make a Drop-down form in a PDF auto-populate a text box [Bluebeam]

Tags: javascript, pdf

I am trying to have a drop down form that is populated with contacts populate a text box that contains the company information and address of that contact.

I have a small amount of knowledge in Javascript and have tried the following code:

```
var one = this.getField("Contact");
var two = this.getField("Company");

if (one.value == 'John Doe') {
    two.value = 'Company1';
} else if (one.value == 'Jane Doe') {
    two.value = 'Company2';
}
```

Is there anyone that can point me in the right direction?  I have looked for similar questions but none I could find offered a solution for this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

Bluebeam is a relatively smart PDF viewer, and it should be possible to do some JavaScripting. You'd have to check whether it works, however; I don't have access to Bluebeam, and can not test it myself). A possible solution would look like this:

a) you create a document-level JavaScript which contains an array of the contact info (which may contain more than just the company name, but also address etc.. This array could look like this:

```
var contarr = new Array() ;
contarr[0] = ["Contact Person", "Company", "Address", "City", "State", "Zip"] ;
contarr[1] = ["John Doe", "Does and Donz", "Main Street", "Doetown", "TX", "99999"]
// and so on
```

b) In your Dropdown, you add the contact person name, and as return value, you add the index number of its entry in the contarr array. Let's assume we call the dropdown "Contact".

c) In an independent text field, you add the following Calculation script:

```
var sele = this.getField("Contact").value ;
this.getField("Company").value = contarr[sele][1] ;
this.getField("Address").value = contarr[sele][2] ;
this.getField("City").value = contarr[sele][3] ;
this.getField("State").value = contarr[sele][4] ;
this.getField("Zip").value = contarr[sele][5] ;
```

If everything is set up correctly, and you reopened the document, you should be able to select a contact, and the rest of the information would fill the according fields.