# Bluebeam Auto-fill form fields based on drop-down

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, drop-down-menu, autofill

I am a newbie to Bluebeam and i have been tasked with making a form where text fields are auto populated based on a drop-down selection. The drop-down is a Contact and the auto fill areas are Title, Email and Telephone. I have found some Javascript that looks like it may work ([How to make a Drop-down form in a PDF auto-populate a text box [Bluebeam]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29977293/how-to-make-a-drop-down-form-in-a-pdf-auto-populate-a-text-box-bluebeam)), but i don't know how to actually set it up in Bluebeam.

I have the drop-down entered into my form, and i have form text boxes created for the auto-fill areas. But where do i put this, if this is the code i would use:

```
ar contarr = new Array() ;
contarr[0] = ["Contact", "Title", "Email", "Telephone"] ;
contarr[1] = ["Miguel", "Facilities Manager", "Miguel@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.9285 | Cell"]
contarr[2] = ["Jerry", "Facilities Manager", "Jerry@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.8642 | Cell"]
contarr[3] = ["Andrew", "Engineer", "Andrew@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.0985 | Cell"]
contarr[4] = ["Tom", "Director", "Tom@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.5987 | Cell"]
contarr[5] = ["Richard", "Supervisor", "Richard@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.7193 | Cell"]
```

I found this part of an answer:

"In your Dropdown, you add the contact person name, and as return value, you add the index number of its entry in the contarr array. Let's assume we call the dropdown "Contact"."

I'm not sure how to do that. I've added the contact person name, but where do i put a "return value" and an "index number"? I've no idea what a "contarr array" is.

It also said in an independent file I would put:

```
var sele = this.getField("Contact").value ;
this.getField("Title").value = contarr[sele][1] ;
this.getField("Email").value = contarr[sele][2] ;
this.getField("Telephone").value = contarr[sele][3]
```

Is an independent field just a regular text box that i hide somewhere on my pdf or are we talking like an excel worksheet or something?

I have searched all over the web and can't find step by step instructions. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that could be a document level script to achieve what you want. The code assumes you have 4 form fields, a drop down named "Contacts" and then the 3 text boxes that are "Title", "Email", and "Telephone".

The code populates the combo box with the names from contarr, and then adds code to respond to the active item changing in order to update the text boxes.

```
var contarr = new Array() ;
contarr[0] = ["Contact", "Title", "Email", "Telephone"] ;
contarr[1] = ["Miguel", "Facilities Manager", "Miguel@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.9285 | Cell"]
contarr[2] = ["Jerry", "Facilities Manager", "Jerry@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.8642 | Cell"]
contarr[3] = ["Andrew", "Engineer", "Andrew@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.0985 | Cell"]
contarr[4] = ["Tom", "Director", "Tom@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.5987 | Cell"]
contarr[5] = ["Richard", "Supervisor", "Richard@gmail.com", "+1 555.555.7193 | Cell"]

var names = [];
for (var i = 0; i < contarr.length; i++) {
    names.push(contarr[i][0]);
}

this.getField("Contacts").setItems(names);
this.getField("Contacts").setAction("Keystroke", "onContactSwitch(event.value);");

selectContact(0);   // Choose initial contact

function onContactSwitch(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < contarr.length; i++) {
        if (contarr[i][0] == name) {
            selectContact(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}

function selectContact(i) {
    this.getField("Title").value = contarr[i][1];
    this.getField("Email").value = contarr[i][2];
    this.getField("Telephone").value = contarr[i][3];
}
```